# Explicit vs. implicit dependency handling in require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'll use what I'm actually doing as an example.  I have a knockout custom binding that depends on a jquery plugin that itself depends on jQuery UI that of course depends on jQuery.  There is another file that depends on another plugin, and another file that depends on jQuery UI, etc.  In require.config.js I have:

```
shim: {
    "jquery-ui": {exports: "$", deps: ["jquery"]},
    "jquery-plugin1": {exports: "$", deps: ["jquery-ui"]},
    "jquery-plugin2": {exports: "$", deps: ["jquery-ui"]}
}
```

This works, and then in corresponding files I may do:

```
define(["jquery-plugin1"], function ($) {
```

However, I could also do:

```
define(["jquery", "jquery-ui", "jquery-plugin1"], function ($) {
```

There is also the case where a file may depend on both plugins:

```
// which one?
define(["jquery-plugin1", "jquery-plugin2"], function ($) {
define(["jquery", "jquery-ui", "jquery-plugin1", "jquery-plugin2"], function ($){
```

There may also be other dependencies such as knockout custom bindings (which don't need to export anything) so I may end up with:

```
define(["jquery-plugin1", "model1", "model2",
"ko-custom1", "ko-custom2", "ko-custom3",
"jquery-plugin2"],
function ($, m1, m2) {
```

This file may also depend on jQuery UI (which depends on jQuery), but those are both loaded implicitly via the plugins.

My question is is it better to be explicit about all requirements (i.e. include jQuery and jQuery-UI in `define`) and possibly leave off the exports, or is the less-verbose nested dependency handling preferred?

Comment: I prefer having jQuery as a global variable - it just makes things easier though some people might have a strong opinion about that. I run the same scripts that uses the global jQuery variable in Node when doing unit tests so it really isn't an issue. You could probably also include jQuery UI as a global variable, but do you REALLY need it? There's usually a less bloated library that does what you need just as good or even better. But if you use it extensively thoughout your application, I'd put that in the global namespace as well. You won't have to deal with shims or load orders that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question and becomes very relevant when using something like AngularJS dependency injection as those dependencies need to exist before the module is registered. So this won't work:

```
define(['angular'],function (angular) {
  return angular.module('myModule', ['mySubmodule']);
});

// Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mySubmodule' is not available!
```

You need to define the AMD dependency as well:

```
define(['angular','./mySubmodule'],function (angular) {
  return angular.module('myModule', ['mySubmodule']);
});
```

---

It might be subjective but I find it easier to reason about it by having each module define it's own dependencies **explicitly** and letting requireJS resolve them instead of leaving it up to *faith* that an out-of-scope module has already defined them which breaks modularity.

By doing this you also know that your AMD modules can be tested independently without rewiring the missing dependency.